# Remove prefix from all mysql table names of a database

Tags: mysql

*I want to remove prefix from all table names in MySQL

I have a **test** database with more than 100 tables, so i don't want to go through a manual process or renaming each table.

e.g
**ci_categories**
**ci_products**

expected output:
**categories**
**products**

i want to remove prefix from all table, that is **ci_**

Is there a MySQL query to achieve this?

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can change prefixes in all tables in my MySQL DB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466101/how-i-can-change-prefixes-in-all-tables-in-my-mysql-db)

Comment: Does every table has a prefix **ci_** ?

Comment: yes every table has ci_ prefix.

Comment: I think this question has a tweak. (Y) it's more about updating a whole database table names rather than updating a single table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a mysql stored procedure in order to change the table names since there's no other straight forward way to change all the table names through a single query.

```
delimiter //
CREATE  PROCEDURE `ChangeTableNameProcedure`()
BEGIN

    DECLARE int_val INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE my_outer_cursor_done INT DEFAULT FALSE; 
    DECLARE my_oldTable VARCHAR(100);
    DECLARE my_newTable VARCHAR(100);

    DECLARE tableNameCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT TABLE_NAME oldName,
    CONCAT(SUBSTRING(TABLE_NAME,POSITION('ci_' IN TABLE_NAME) + 3)) newName
    FROM information_schema.tables 
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'ci_%';
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET my_outer_cursor_done = TRUE;



OPEN tableNameCursor;
    OUTER_CURSOR_LOOP: LOOP
            FETCH FROM tableNameCursor INTO my_oldTable,my_newTable;

                    IF my_outer_cursor_done THEN
                        CLOSE tableNameCursor;
                        LEAVE OUTER_CURSOR_LOOP;
                    END IF;
                    SET @old = my_oldTable;
                    SET @new = my_newTable;
                    SET @statement = CONCAT('RENAME TABLE ',@old,' TO ',@new);

                    PREPARE stmt FROM @statement;
                    EXECUTE stmt;
                    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;


                    END LOOP OUTER_CURSOR_LOOP;


    END//
```

**N:B:**

1. I've assumed that all the table names in your database has a prefix
   **ci_**.
2. You have to put your database name in TABLE_SCHEMA=
   'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME' clause.
3. Note that **+ 3** stands for the new table name where first three
   characters will be skipped (if your old table name is 'ci_old_table'
   then your new table name would be 'old_table'. Note that 'ci_' first
   three characters have been skipped in new table name.)
4. After creating the procedure you need to call it simply by its name.
   The syntax is `Call ChangeTableNameProcedure();`
5. Please make sure while creating the procedure you are not ignoring
   the delimeter //

Comment: You are most welcome.Glad to know it worked for you.!! :D