# copy tables structure automatically and change tables name mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So basically I have a  database in MySQL which has a bunch of tables that have many diffrent names for example '`table_data`' I would like to copy and  rename all of these tables by adding for example '`_city`' so it will be:    '`table_data_city`' Any ideas about how to do this with a simple script?
notice i  want to copy the structure only.

Comment: no, i have no idea how to do it, i know how to do it manually in phpmyadmin but it wil take so much time, cuz i have many tables... i was wondering if there is a way to do it automatically.

Comment: Wow, a database with a bunch of tables, who would have imagined?!

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: How many tables is many? It may be quicker to export the table structure, open your editor and add `_city` to each, rather than write a script.

Comment: around 120 table  , and it wouldnt work because it has many diffrent names, that means i will have to type the new name and search for it to replace it, it would be same as doin it in phpmyadmin

Comment: yes i want to keep the name and add a string to it, for example table_data  i rename it to table_data_city

Comment: yes sir, they will have the same previous name and we add _city to them..for example:  table_data = table_data_city, table_log = table_log_city.... and then i will have to do... table_data = table_data_city2...it would take forever to do it manually

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove prefix from all mysql table names of a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103436/remove-prefix-from-all-mysql-table-names-of-a-database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this php code

```
<?php
$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db_name");
$query="SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables where table_schema='db_name';";

$result=mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$tables=array();
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $query="RENAME TABLE ".$row[0]." TO ".$row[0]."_city";
    mysqli_query($conn,$query);
}
```

Comment: ty so much , your script doesnt copy but it changes  the name , so i will just copy the tables in diffrent database and then rename them , and then join them to the original one. i have a little problem , it doesnt change the name of tables  with these names :"table-log" but if its 'table_log' it works, any solution?

Comment: fixed it was just quotes problem ;  $query=' RENAME TABLE `'.$row[0].'` TO `'.$row[0].'_city`'; ty alot!